# Why is \DeclareRobustCommand[*] still used by LaTeX?

Tags: macros, latex-base, protected-macro

As LaTeX requires eTeX now it would be much easier to replace all the definitions of robust commands with `\DeclareRobustCommand[*]...` by `\protected[\long]\def...`, wouldn't it?

Which advatages come along with the the complicated definition of `\DeclareRobustCommand`? It should be also mentioned that it is immpossible to find out the definition of a command defined this way by using `\show` or `\meaning`. Example: When you write `\meaning\TeX` you get `macro:->\protect \TeX` which seems to be nonsense as a command always expanding to itselt lets TeX crash. Please help me understandig this.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

% latex.ltx contains
% \DeclareRobustCommand\TeX{T\kern-.1667em\lower.5ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX\@}
\meaning\TeX% macro:->\protect \TeX % This is useless.

\TeX

% define \TeX by \protected\def
\protected\def\TeX{T\kern-.1667em\lower.5ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX\@}
\meaning\TeX% The real definition is shown.

\TeX

\end{document}
```

Comment: On `\meaning\TeX`, the expansion has a command containing a space: that's the entire trick of `\DeclareRobustCommand`. It might _look_ the same, but it's not.

Comment: More widely, you are asking two questions: why not use e-TeX for everything, and how does the 'classical' mechanism work

Comment: The main difference is that the definition of  \protect can be changed. That means that you can get different behaviour in different contexts, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/161006/2388

Comment: Try `\expandafter\show\csname TeX\space\endcsname`. Note that `\DeclareRobustCommand` was introduced long before LaTeX required e-TeX. This comment might be relevant: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/513337/expandable-test-for-an-empty-token-list-methods-performance-and-robustness#comment1298131_513337 :-)

Comment: Thanks @PhelypeOleinik, so there are historical reasons.

Comment: @user125730 Yes. We are moving some commands to e-TeX `\protected` (for example: https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/203), but moving all of them would break LaTeX everywhere. Also there's the advantage that Ulrike mentioned that `\protect` can have different meanings, while a `\protected` macro has the same protection everywhere.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik: But could you give an example where the protection by `\protected` would fail and where `\DeclareRobustCommand` is really necessary?

Comment: I mean "fail" in the sense that `\protected\def` cannot substitute `\DeclareRobustCommand` to get the desired result.

Comment: @user125730 One obvious problem are packages that rely on commands having their `\DeclareRobustCommand` meaning. Other than that, try `\protected\def\end#1{\csname​ end#1​\endcsname\@checkend​{#1}\expandafter\endgroup​\if​@endpe​\@doendpe​\fi\if​@ignore​\@ignorefalse\ignorespaces​\fi​}` and then use `\begin{tabular}{|cc|}a&b\end{tabular}`.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik: OK, this is an argument, as a Plain TeX user I didn't think about packages. But when I insert your definition of `\end` (but without the `tabular` no output is produced: `LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{​}.` `(job aborted, no legal \end found)`

Comment: @user125730 Well, there _are_ packages for Plain. Not as many, sure, and definitely not so dependent on how the format is defined, so the impacts of a change like that are smaller. `\end{}`? Seems like you have a typo somewhere. Try this: `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}\makeatletter\protected\def\end#1{\csname end#1\endcsname\@checkend{#1}\expandafter\endgroup\if@endpe\@doendpe\fi\if@ignore\@ignorefalse\ignorespaces\fi}\begin{tabular}{|cc|}a&b\\\end{tabular}\end{document}`. Also, in my `tabular` example it was missing a ``\\``. It doesn't throw an error, but the output is wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/what-is-the-difference-between-fragile-and-robust-commands)